# How to compare U.S. Census demographic data to a population-level dataset? E.g. how to approach a question like are women underrepresented on boards?

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, sample, population, demography

I have a population-level dataset of all people who testified on environmental legislation in a single year. I have data on all witness's ages, races, genders, and ethnicities. This dataset is not a sample of those who testified -- it is everyone!

I want to know if the demographic breakdown of those who testify is significantly different than the demographic breakdown of the state. In particular, I want to know if White people are overrepresented among the population of those who testify, assuming that "overrepresented" means "a larger proportion of White people testified than the proportion of voting-age White people in the state".

Example of the data I am comparing:
Let's say 800 people testified in a year and 20% are Asian, 5% are Black, and 75% are White.
Let's say the 5mil-person state is 10% Asian, 60% White, and 30% Black.

Do I simply report the difference in percentages, as my dataset is for the entire population of witnesses?

Are there any statistical tests I could run? For example, Pearson's Chi-square test?

Comment: You make a subtle but potentially huge error in slipping silently from referring to those who testified *in a given year* to "those who testify" *generally.*  If your purpose is only to describe that particular year, you could do so (no statistical testing is warranted), but if you attempt to draw any conclusions then you risk being very mistaken, because this approach cuts off any consideration of the *processes* that led people to testify.  You have only a *sample* of the results of those processes.  Thus I would urge you--strongly--to abandon the idea that you have an entire population.

Comment: Expanding on the previous comment, “population” is the term the gets used in introductory classes, but a “data-generating process” (i.e. nature) is usually the better way to think about it (closer to the mathematics of distributions and random variables). Your situation sounds like a place to consider a data-generating process, rather than a finite population.